# How do I get start date, end date and location of an EKEventStore function

Tags: ekeventstore

i have this code which reads calendar data from the calendar app.

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted,
                                                                    NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Import" message:@"Import Unavailable" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    // Create the start date components
    NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
    NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                  toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                 options:0];
    // Create the end date components
    NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 1;
    NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents
                                                       toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                      options:0];
    // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
    NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo
                                                            endDate:oneYearFromNow
                                                          calendars:nil];
    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    for (id name in events)
        NSLog (@"%@", name);
```

it logs full details of the result which outputs:

```
EKEvent <0x937c410>
{    title =        Meeting w/ David; 
     location =     (null); 
     calendar =     EKCalendar <0x938a650> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #1BADF8;}; 
     alarms =       (null); 
     URL =          (null); 
     lastModified = 2014-03-27 11:52:39 +0000; 
     timeZone =     Asia/Manila (GMT+8) offset 28800 
}; 
     location =     (null); 
     startDate =    2014-03-28 04:00:00 +0000; 
     endDate =      2014-03-28 05:00:00 +0000; 
     allDay =       0; 
     floating =     0; 
     recurrence =   (null); 
     attendees =    (null) 
};
```

what I want is, I only want to get start date, end date and location on 3 separate arrays..how do I get these?

Answer (score 0):

BITTER BOYS :(
heres the answer to my question:

modified the last code to

```
NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    for (id name in events){
        NSString *theName = [name valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog (@"%@", theName);
        //NSLog (@"%@", name);
    }
```